# How do I change a year in a string where the year occur at the end of the string?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to increment a column in my table wp_terms.

I have this

```
UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '2009', '2008');

UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '2010', '2009');

UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '2011', '2010');

UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '2012', '2011');

UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '2013', '2012');

UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '2014', '2013');

UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '2015', '2014');

UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '2016', '2015');

UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '2017', '2016');

UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, '2018', '2017');
```

The issue is that years will be automatically replacing by an another. 
For example : 2008 is replaced by 2009 on the first line. On the second, 2009 is replaced by 2010. But it will impact my first update because all of 2009 will be replace by 2010.

My idea is that i want to change them in the same time :

```
update wp_terms
set slug = slug - 1
WHERE name LIKE '%20%';
```

But it didn't work because my permalink become something like

> http://localtestwww.mywebsite.com/category/-1/

Moreover, in this column, i also have another slug which don't have to be changed, just want to change the years of slug which contains years.

How do I change a year in a string where the year occur at the end of the string?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Couldn't you just run the updates in reverse order? First set 2017 to 2018, then 2016 to 2017 and so on?

Comment: Why don't you run these update queries in reverse order?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @waka and Nico but it didn't work because if i run these update queries in reverse order it will change : 
firstly, the 2018 in 2017, then it will change all the 2017 in 2016, etc.

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon , it was almost the same yes, the answer about 2 days ago was good and worked for me. But now i don't want to do the same thing, or it can works maybe but if i did like i said in my post, it will put all slugs with no years in like '-1'

Comment: When you say no years do you mean slug is sometimes stored as null or something else.

Comment: Yes, some slugs are like only strings.

Comment: I think you are going to have to write a procedure for this to extract the date from the string, amend it and write it back.

Comment: Oh ok. I have really no idea how to do that, i'm not an expert of SQL, is it hard to do ?

Comment: I would hang fire on that given your last comment in nicks's answer.

Comment: Yes @P.Salmon , i edited my post, i thought it was clear but not for you and i recognize my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RLIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to match the slug with valid year values using a regular expression; this one looks for the slug value ending in 4 digits. Then we use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to extract the string and trailing year, which we subtract one from before we concatenate the two parts back together:

```
UPDATE wp_terms
SET slug = CONCAT(LEFT(slug, LENGTH(slug) - 4), RIGHT(slug, 4) - 1)
WHERE slug RLIKE '[[:digit:]]{4}$' AND RIGHT(slug, 4) > 2008
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=be5a4ffecb654400dd9e7285b23f13c4)

Comment: And what can i do for slugs like "category2018","string2018" ? I also want to put them as "category2017","string2017" , not only the slug which is "2018" ?

Comment: I have edited my question Nick, maybe it's better for your comprehension now.

Comment: @Tweak can the year occur **anywhere** in the string? e.g. '2013stuff', 'my2014year' etc.?

Comment: No @Nick, it's always at the end of my string. It's something like '2012', 'doc2012', 'category2013', 'stuff2014', etc.

Comment: What version of MySQL do you have?

Comment: @Tweak 'it's always at the end of my string'  - that's not what you said in your last edit

Comment: @Nick 8.0.16 i guess, i'm on MySQL Workbench

Comment: @Tweak I've updated my answer. It will work on versions of MySQL 5.x as well as 8.x

Comment: Ok @Nick i'm trying to adapt your answer on my database and in function of my code. Can we keep in touch if i have any issues on this ? I think you put me on the right way and it can be good

Comment: @Tweak absolutely. No need to accept until you have tested the code and it works for you.

Comment: @Nick i forget something. I had just to put -1 on the year on every year AFTER 2008. 2008 had to stay 2008, but 2009 has to be 2008, and 2010 to be 2009, etc.

Comment: @Tweak see my edit. It won't update any year earlier than 2009.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192900/discussion-between-tweak-and-nick).

Comment: Hey @Nick can you come in the chat please ?